# Trying to display checked in check box if value equal 1

Tags: php, checked

basically im trying to display a check mark ,if value in  database is equal to 1 i want the checkbox to be checked and if its equal 0 display an empty checkbox!

```
$sql_works="SELECT task.taskId, task.adminId, task.taskName, task.day, task.month, task.year, task.taskText,task.checkMark FROM task INNER JOIN administrator ON administrator.id = task.adminId Where taskId =" . $_GET['id'];         

                $result_works = mysql_query( $sql_works )or die("error");


                if ( !$result_works  ) 
                {
                    die ('Query Error, Please try again later ...');
                }

                $nb_works = mysql_num_rows ( $result_works );

                if ($nb_works > 0 ){
                    $row_works = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result_works);
    $checkmark= "$row_works['checkMark']";

    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked = "<?php echo $row_works['checkMark'];?>" /> <label for="custom">Task done!</label>
```

Heres my Database:

```
    -- Dumping database structure for workspacedb
    CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `workspacedb` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;
    USE `workspacedb`;


    -- Dumping structure for table workspacedb.task
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `task` (
      `taskId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `adminId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `taskName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
      `day` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
      `month` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `year` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
      `taskText` text,
      `checkmark` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`taskId`),
      KEY `FK_task_administrator` (`adminId`),
      CONSTRAINT `FK_task_administrator` FOREIGN KEY (`adminId`) REFERENCES `administrator` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

    -- Dumping data for table workspacedb.task: ~7 rows (approximately)
    /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `task` DISABLE KEYS */;
    INSERT INTO `task` (`taskId`, `adminId`, `taskName`, `day`, `month`, `year`, `taskText`, `checkmark`) VALUES
        (3, 21, 'task1', 6, '1', 2015, 'this is a test task 1', 0),
        (5, 21, 'comptask', 5, '4', 2014, 'this is a completed task', 1),
        (7, 21, 'tasss', 4, '3', 2015, '', 0),
        (8, 20, 'taaa', 2, '1', 2014, 'jjjjjj', 0),
        (9, 22, 'task1212', 1, '2', 2015, 'jjjjj', 0),
        (10, 21, 'task4', 1, '12', 2015, 'skksksmnd, cs cdnms cdn ms cds dcm sdc', 1),
        (11, 22, 'task22', 4, '1', 2014, 'testttstststststtstZL  awsidpoiawjde  awed i0owde r0ju qewdr 0qweurd woqej fdoqe fdoqe oijqeddij qe', 0);
    /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `task` ENABLE KEYS */;
    /*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=IFNULL(@OLD_SQL_MODE, '') */;
    /*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=IF(@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS IS NULL, 1, @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS) */;
    /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
```

Comment: This `$row_works['checkMark']` contain `0` or `1` value?

Comment: You need to either limit the result set to one using the LIMIT syntax or you need to account for multiple results in the result set by using a loop to generate the checkboxes.

Comment: $row_works['checkMark'] has value of 1

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $isChecked = $row_works['checkMark'] == 1 ? 'checked="checked"' : null; ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" <?= $isChecked;?> /><label for="custom">Task done!</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Proper syntax for checked inupt would be

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="myCheckbox" />
```

So the php code would be

```
<input type="checkbox" <?php if ($row_works['checkMark'] == 1) { 'checked="checked"'; } ?>  name="myCheckbox" />
```

Comment: You must echo the string inside the `if` statement

Answer (score 0):

Right. I find this is easier to read:

```
<?php
$sChecked = "";
if ($row_works['checkMark'] == 1) {
    $sChecked = ' checked="checked"';
}
?>
<input type="checkbox" <?=$sChecked?>  name="myCheckbox" />
```